# How to verify the multiple warning messages in Selenium webdriver using Java?

Tags: if-statement

I am in learning stage of Selenium webdriver.
I want to validate the Login page warning messages in single code. I am trying "if else if" condition but whenever I run the code only "if condition" is working "else if and else condition" are not working.

I am trying to validation the second warning message "username was empty reenter".

Here is my code,

```
WebElement useralertElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'User not found.')]]"));

String Actualusralert=useralertElement.getText();

String Expectedusralert="following error occurred during login: User not found.";
          
WebElement nouserElement =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='username was empty reenter']"));

String Expectednouseralert="username was empty reenter";

String Actualnouseralert=nouserElement.getText();    
          
          if(Actualusralert.equals(Expectedusralert)) {
            System.out.println("Enter valid username");
          }
          else if(Expectednouseralert.equals(Actualnouseralert))
          {
              System.out.println("Please enter the username");
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("Entered username is valid");
          }
```

I am getting an exception as
"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[text()[contains(.,'User not found.')]]"}"

Any help would be appreciated..